# How do I take a users input for their login email and find a file that matches it?

Tags: c#

Here is my code, I've tried using Streamreader but it won't work when I put in the file path.

```
    private void LoginFormbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("/Participants/");
        using (reader)
            if(File.Exists("txtEmailID.Text" + ".txt"))
            {
                Userform Userf = new Userform();
                Userf.Show();
                MessageBox.Show("Success!");
            }
    }
```

Comment: Do you really have `"txtEmailID.Text" ` in your code, so *with* quotes?

Comment: What error message / exception do you get? Please make sure to add that into the question.

Comment: You don't even use the StreamReader. Did you mean `if(File.Exists(Path.Combine("Participants", txtEmailID.Text + ".txt")))`

Comment: You can only open a StreamReader to a **file**, not a **folder**. The `File.Exists` will look in whatever the "current folder" is, *not* in that /Participants/ folder (it doesn't know/care about that StreamReader that you opened). You may want [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
if(File.Exists("txtEmailID.Text" + ".txt"))
```

into this:

```
if(File.Exists(txtEmailID.Text + ".txt"))
```

Also i would have declare the StreamReader like this:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("/Participants/"))
{
// your code
}
```

Comment: That looks better but I still get the file path error 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file 'C:\Participants\'.'

Comment: Where does the file located?